# tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is not working properly and shape/rank error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

Trying to implement Skip-Thought vectors (Sentence encoder for downstream activities like sentiment classification, similarity match and so on) with below training details.

1. 50,000 Sentence - Training sample (On an average of 10-15 words per sentence size)
2. 20,000 Unique vocab list
3. Base reference source code from [Tensor skip-thought from github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/2c4dc0c00aba5dde21923dd4f8aa1584e8ec67af/research/skip_thoughts/skip_thoughts/skip_thoughts_model.py#L292-L308)

But found something strange to me in the process of loss calculations and below is reference snapshot, Target and Logits are in different shape and size. Is it valid or do i need to change the 'num_outputs' to targets.get_shape().as_list()[0]

Error message while executing losses line item-

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1280,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (128, 20000)).
```

[image]

Comment: Its my bad that the initial shape of decoder_output is (batch X max_len X embedding_dim) confused with states (batch X embedding_dim) but its actually getting outputs NOT the state), so its obviously matching with targets shape. (sparse_softmax_cross_enthropy_with_logits) Make sure labels/targets first dimensions is matching with logits first dimensions and when the logits rank is 2 then labels/targets rank should be 1 (3 then 2 and so on)